# Confusion with github branch protection rule

Tags: github, repo

I have encountered a problem with my repo that i have enabled branch protection rule in github on main branch the settings are default of protection rule provided by github.

As i am the owner i have a Personal access token that i to do push request but the problem is even i am the admin the branch protection rule stops me from push to that branch.

How to resolve it or if i am understanding wrong then what should i do then ??

i expect that branch protection rule should stop other person to do commit but it restricts admin also

Comment: In the GitHub settings for branch protection, there's an option to enforce the protection for admins too, or not. Check and make sure it's not enforced for admins.

Comment: Sure i will look up on that

Comment: Glad you could fix it.